# animated sprite images in navigation bar buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, sprite

Working on an iOS app right now - was curious to if it is possible to use an animated sprite for a button in the Top Nav Bar. For example, having the hands on a clock button continually turn via a looped animation (like a web GIF - but better). Is this possible, and if so, how difficult is it?

Thanks!

Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [`animatedImageNamed:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW42) and [`animatedImageWithImages:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW43) methods of `UIImage`.  You will have to put each frame of each sprite in a separate file, or (if you don't want to split up your animated GIF) use the `ImageIO` framework to create separate `UIImage` objects for each frame in the GIF.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out - do you think it's possible/practical to apply this method to a Navigation button? Or should I reconsider?

Comment: I tested it by setting `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.image` to an animated `UIImage`.